# How do I load a child collection of entities when a link table (and class) exists?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

My many-to-many relationship requires payload data in the link table (the weight field).

```
public class Formula
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FormulaComponent> FormulaComponents { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FormulaComponent> FormulaComponents { get; set; }
}

public class FormulaComponent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int FormulaID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FormulaID")]
    public virtual Formula Formula { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ComponentID")]
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

    public double? Weight { get; set; }
}
```

I'm struggling with how to use linq to load child data for a parent entity (components for a specific formula). My code was working before payload data was required. When I had no class representing the link table and the child was a property of the parent (`ICollection<Component>`) here is how I loaded child data in a disconnected scenario:

```
_context.Entry(Formula).Collection(f => f.Components).Load();
```

Since the child collection is no longer a property of the parent I tried this:

```
_context.Entry(Formula).Collection(f => f.FormulaComponents).Load();
```

But that only gets the link table data. Since the Components are a property of the link table I suspect I need to add a Select or SelectMany but I can't get the syntax right:

```
_context.Entry(Formula).Collection(f => f.FormulaComponents.Select(???)).Load();
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here. I didn't realize that the child Components entities were eager loaded along with FormulaComponents. So this line of code (in the question) actually worked:

```
_context.Entry(Formula).Collection(f => f.FormulaComponents).Load();
```

So when I said "But that only gets the link table data" I was actually wrong. It loads exactly what I wanted loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, at the moment I have no possability to test the solution, but maybe it will work.

```
_context.Entry(Formula).Collection(f => f.FormulaComponents).Load();
_context.Entry(Formula.FormulaComponents).Reference(fc => fc.Component).Load();
```

Because you have a **many-to-many** relation (*Formula - Component*) with attributes in your relation table (*FormulaComponent*) you have in reality one **one-to-many** (*Formula - FormulaComponent*) and one **many-to-one** (*FormulaComponent - Component*) relation.
Therefore you have to load the collection (FormulaComponent) first, followed by the references of each entry in the collection to Component.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I like the explanation but your second line does not compile on fc.Component. The compiler says fc is an ICollection<FormulaComponent>. Intellisense gives options such as fc.Select.

Comment: I have to add that I have solved my problem. I didn't realize that the Components entities were eager loaded along with FormulaComponents. So when I said "that only gets the link table data" I was actually wrong. It loads exactly what I wanted loaded. I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet so I haven't posted it at this point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, great to hear about it.